# How to draw in another window's form

Tags: c#, winapi, hook

I want to draw a red box with values inside it (like a watermark) into another window's form. How can i achieve this? It's for debugging purposes, and the framework I'm developing on is unable to use Console.write() so i thought of this.

Thanks !

Comment: By rectangle, do you mean a Textbox that is not inside your application (like writing into another application textbox?

Comment: no more like a pixel overlay, that i can draw stuff onto. Like some sort of watermark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Mithrandir says, System.Diagnostics.Debug is probably a better bet.  Or a debugger.

If you really want to "annotate" another window by drawing further information on it, it's easier to create a transparent, captionless, borderless, always-on-top window, draw the information on that and place it over the target window.  This gives the same effect without interfering with the original window.

Answer (score 1):

Try using System.Diagnostics.Debug. That what it's for.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your original form is "Form1" and another is "FormAnother".

Form another should have a public Label or TextBox.

Then you'd simply do something in this style:

```
private void DebugAnotherForm(string msg) {
  var form = new FormAnother();
  form.Show();

  form.myPublicLabel.ForeColor = Colors.Red;
  form.myPublicLabel.Text = msg;
}
```